# Issue with cropped images in flutter_camera_overlay

Tags: flutter, cropper, camera-overlay

I am using the [flutter_camera_overlay](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_camera_overlay) plugin to achieve a cropped image of the card, but it's returning the original image instead of cropped one.

Example on how should work:

[image: Preview]

Comment: Can you share the code snippet of your implementation

Comment: Please provide a `code snippet` of your work.

Comment: here is code snippet... am using example provided by plugin.. please check the example code snippet given in plugin example section, as am unable to provide here due to comment length limit

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provided any example code you are trying i will show you an example of the usage of this plugin to get the cropped image. Maybe it will help you understand.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_camera_overlay/flutter_camera_overlay.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Uint8List? _croppedImageBytes;

  void _onPicture(PictureData pictureData) async {
    final croppedImageBytes = await FlutterCameraOverlay.cropImage(
      pictureData.bytes!,
      pictureData.width!,
      pictureData.height!,
      left: 100,
      top: 100,
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
    );

    setState(() {
      _croppedImageBytes = croppedImageBytes;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Camera Overlay'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: FlutterCameraOverlay(
              onPicture: _onPicture,
            ),
          ),
          if (_croppedImageBytes != null)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Card(
                child: Image.memory(
                  _croppedImageBytes!,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: some method are not defined in this plugin, may be am using some other version, can you please tell me package version, tnxx

Comment: What is your error ill try to help you

Comment: every method u used is undefined in package